# How to Push a Session Value to a Textfield in different aspx page

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008

Hello i have 2 different aspx pages.
Page 1 is the main page with a Textfield.
Page 2 is another page were i can add members and its also in a frame of page 1.

In Page 2 i count the members and save it to a Session:

```
 Dim anzahlExterneTeilnehmer As Integer = BookITVbSQL.SQLrunScalarBookit(externeTeilnehmerSQL)

    Session("anzahlExterneTeilnehmer") = anzahlExterneTeilnehmer
```

The Textfield in Page 1 should show me the Result in the Textfield in realtime.

is this possible?

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: You mean value saved in session in page2 should be shown in textfield of page1?

Comment: yes but in realtime, when i add a new member the session changes its value,too

Comment: Is it ok if the page1's textfield value is updated on its page load?

Comment: i dont want to refresh the whole page to see the current value. isnt it possible to refresh just the textfield?

Answer (score 0):

You can do

Page 2 Code behind:

```
  Dim anzahlExterneTeilnehmer As Integer =       BookITVbSQL.SQLrunScalarBookit(externeTeilnehmerSQL)

  Session("anzahlExterneTeilnehmer") = anzahlExterneTeilnehmer
```

Page 1 Code behind:

```
If Session("anzahlExterneTeilnehmer") Is Nothing Then
    'Session is not loaded on page 2
Else
    ' Session is loaded on page 2
     txtTextfield.Text = Session("anzahlExterneTeilnehmer").ToString
End If
```

Regards

Comment: but how can i update just the textfield. when i add the code in page load, i must refresh everytime to see the current count

Comment: is it pssibe to acces textbox1.text from page2 directly?

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can do it in page1's Page_Load:

```
If Session("anzahlExterneTeilnehmer") IsNot Nothing Then
    TextBox1.Text = Session("anzahlExterneTeilnehmer").ToString()
End If
```

Every time you open page1, the session value if exists, is copied to textbox's text property

Comment: the problem is that page 2 is in a frame of page1 so i dont want to refresh the whole page

Comment: is it pssibe to acces textbox1.text from page2 directly?

Comment: No it is not possible. Passing data across pages can be done only through sessions, cookies, etc. You ill need some event to be triggered in page1 to obtain the data from the session.